# Laravel - load new content from DB using ajax dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am still learning about how Ajax works and I encountered this problem:

`@getDashboard` Controller:

```
$data = Post::latest()->get();

return view('view', ['data'] => $data);
```

`view.blade.php` Page:

```
<div>
    @foreach($data as $post)
        <p>{{ $post->ad_title }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This loads all posts from the database, but new ones appear only on refresh. How can i load new posts from database without refreshing, i suppose using AJAX? Thank you.

Comment: Study some ajax tutorials on the web...this isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Also please read through [ask]. Your question is far too borad and should be narrowed down to specifics

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, i wanted a quick solution, but an actual online course could help me understand much more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so using ajax.

If you want to return JSON from Laravel controller, you can do so very easily. 
Just return the object or array instead of view. Laravel will automatically return JSON as response.

For example:

```
getDashboardJson(){
   return Post::latest()->get();
}
```

Form `Ajax` if you call the corresponding URL of this method, you will get json of all latest posts.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for answering, i managed to use some basic ajax (changing text when i update it in my script using setInterval) But when i try the same for my Post, nothing happens, no errors, just blank page.

Answer (score -1):

What you would want to do is create a function that executes an XMLHTTP Request and then populates your page with the results, then set an interval on that function.

In your PHP, you will want to populate an array with all the data you want in your page. You will then json_encode it and echo it out. Ensure to set your content-type header to application/json.

In your Javascript, you will want to:

- XMLHTTP Request the information
- If there was an error, then handle it
- JSON.Parse it into an array
- Validate it (you may return in your array that no information was found)
- Update your HTML

There are 2 options I would recommend for your ajax. The first is Javascript's built in XMLHTTPRequest method, which you can read up on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The alternative is jQuery.ajax, which you can read up on [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Both pages should conrtain enough information for you to hit the ground running but if not, I would be happy to prepare some examples for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you for linking documentation to help me, but im kind of stuck on the PHP step, i've never sent json to a view, how can i do that? Am i on the right track?  I added this line of code `return response->json($data);` before `return view('view', ['data'] => $data);`  but i have a strong feeling this is not how im supposed to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used Laravel. However, as per the linked document, once you have your data in an array, you will want to do as follows:
`
return response()->json($array);
`
For more information on this, you can look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses